# Create drag and drop between two RV adapters with data changing using ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop, android-viewmodel

In my project I have a recycler view which used for two cases (two states of entity). I want to make items draggable between two RVs, but the DragEvent.ACTION_DROP changes the state of element  which was in under of dropped item. Is it possible to reverse it? Can I get the position of the item where the drop was finished? I have found many other solutions, but in my case the big problem is changing position of items, because they're updating by ViewModel's methods invocation in main fragment.
Maybe I need to choose another way of data showing and create, as example, different adapters with a separate lists?

Code inside the **itemView.setOnTouchListener** in **init block**:

```
    override fun onItemLongTap() {

                    itemView.tag = adapterPosition

                    val shadowBuilder = MyDragShadowBuilder(itemView)
                    val item = ClipData.Item(itemView.tag as? CharSequence)
                    val data = ClipData(
                        itemView.tag as? CharSequence,
                        arrayOf(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN),
                        item
                    )
                    itemView.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, itemView, 0)
                }
            })

            val customDrag = View.OnDragListener { view, event ->
                if (event.action == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP) {
                    onItemDrag?.invoke(items!![adapterPosition])

                }
                true
            }

            itemView.setOnDragListener(customDrag)
```

Invocation in main fragment using *var onItemDrag: ((Item) -> Unit)? = null*:

```
        firstAdapter?.onItemDrag = {
            itemViewModel.changeFirstState(it.id)
        }

        secondAdapter?.onItemDrag = {
            itemViewModel.changeSecondState(it.id)
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I almost forgot to answer on my own question, but I think someone's could have a similar problems, so look.

If you want to use the only one list and update the item's state by DB request, you can just handle "ACTION_DRAG_EXITED" with a lambda at the moment of intersection with another view(using Rect()), but in this case you can't get a position of item which was under(just a fact of collision). This is the case when the RV only shows the data and limits you in actions.

Another solution - create a different lists and replace item's by position changing, then update DB.

Anyway, these are just examples.

In my case, I abandoned the above approaches, because that would be redundant, and only used the intersection check.

So choose the approach that not only does not complicate your code, but also makes it more appropriate and functional.